# Flash Builder not launching - Mac

Tags: flash, eclipse, flex4, flash-builder, flex-builder-3

I have a mac, and I was using Flash Builder (4.5) and my computer crashed and I had to restart. After restarting I could not open Flash Builder, for no matter how many times I try or even restarting my computer again. It shows on the dock, the three vertical lines but besides that, it's doing nothing.

is there any way of opening it up in safe-mode?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to look at the log file Flash Builder/Eclipse generates.

See this post : http://ria.arunkumarm.com/2010/08/error-log-for-frequent-flex-builder.html